# JavaScript / Node.js: Type of declared field

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I have the following object:

```
var info = {

type:String

}
```

what is the best way to turn the String declaration into a type?

I'd rather not do:

```
var info = {

type:typeof('')

}
```

as I'd rather be much more explicit

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to create a schema checker, this info is the schema for a database. the field with String value (in this case 'type:') declares the expected type. thanks for asking.

Comment: You might want to say NodeJS explicitly in the title or in the question itself. The question seems too generic otherwise and not everybody checks the tags (trying to help you from getting down-voted unnecessarily)

Comment: Alex, you may want to add that clarification to your question; that way it's obvious to those coming to the question later (and saves people having to read comments to determine the question).

Comment: this question has been tagged with node.js from the start, which clarification should I add to the question? perhaps remove the JS tag?

Comment: I think the more important bit of info is that this is for type validation. Doesn't really matter whether or not it's Node. This has nothing to do with host objects. Everything being talked about is vanilla ECMAScript.

Comment: I have to say, I am extremely tired of getting downvotes, and votes to close on legitimate questions like this. Who is to blame? And if you would speak up as to why.

Comment: Did one of the answers answer your question?  Can you select one as the best answer to indicate to the community that your question has been answered?  Or do you need to explain further what has not been answered?  FYI, some people downvote when they find the question unclear and questions asking you to clarify don't result in the question becoming clear.  I didn't downvote you in this case, but it was hard to figure out what you were really asking.

Comment: thanks jfriend00, I went with Ennis' answer because it was most clear even though i think your answer is correct also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No reason you can't keep this if you really want to:

```
var info = {

  type:String

}
```

Your validation function could look like this:

```
function check( val, schema ) {
  switch( schema.type ) {
    case String:
      return typeof val === 'string';
    case Number:
      return typeof val === 'number';
  }
}

check( 'foo', info );
```

And of course you could add as many types as you want to that `switch`.

Comment: I am not sure what the val parameter is supposed to be. I just want to pass in String, or Number, or Boolean, and return the typeof those. But I guess this method is to return a boolean as to whether a value is a certain type.. Will edit your answer to make it more explicit - added parens to typeof, now it's clear.

Comment: Uhhh. Nevermind, I guess. I thought you wanted to validate input against a schema. You just want a function that accepts a constructor function and returns it's type? I guess you could do this `function type( F ) { return typeof F() }`.

Answer (score 1):

Names of types in Javascript (e.g. what `typeof x` returns) are lowercase strings, so if you're just trying to set a property that shows you are expecting a string type, then you can do this:

```
var info = {
   type: "string"
}
```

You can see this yourself if you do `console.log(typeof "foo");`.  You will get `"string"` as the resulting type.

You can then use this info to check the type of a variable `x` like this versus what you are expecting:

```
if (typeof x === info.type)
```